# Npm not found when running docker container from node image

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, npm

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:7-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY package.json /src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

I'm trying to complete a [katacoda.com](https://katacoda.com) exercise for [Dockerizing nodejs](https://katacoda.com/courses/docker/3) applications with the Dockerfile above. The build completes but running the image quits immediately and in the docker logs I see:

```
/bin/sh: [npm,: not found
```

I tried running the container in interactive mode with `docker -it nodeapp /bin/bash` which raised the error `docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory".` So I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: try `docker -it nodeapp sh` and then `which npm` to see if npm is installed or not

Comment: because alpine doeesn't have bash hence the above error. try with `sh` and check `npm` later once you're in

Comment: thanks @TuanAnhTran `docker -it nodeapp sh` works and npm is installed and npm start works

Comment: so how come `docker run .... ` doesn't?

Comment: ok so when you run the image, you still got `/bin/sh: [npm,: not found` ?

Comment: it just quits instantly and doesn't appear in `docker ps` running `docker ps -a` i see that it exited and but now there are no logs when i run `docker logs nodeapp`

Comment: i changed it to `CMD npm start` and it works now.

Answer (score 37):

The reason it doesn't work is single quotes

```
CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

should be

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When you don't use double quotes, docker will remove the single quotes and process the command as `[npm, start]`

That is why you see error `[npm,` : not found

Answer (score 6):

I had the same symptom but the problem was slightly different. Writing here in case google leads others in my situation to this link For me the issue was forgetting commas in the `CMD`. So the solution was going from `CMD ["npm" "start"]` to `CMD ["npm", "start"]`.

Comment: i can't believe myself i did this silly mistake