# Why do I get '/bin/sh: [npm,: not found' error when running 'docker run nodeWeb'?

Tags: docker

My docker image name is

```
simpleweb2
```

Here is my docker file:

```
#base Image
FROM node:alpine

#install dependencies
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install

#default command
CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

After built and run the following command

```
docker run simpleweb2
```

I get this error

```
/bin/sh: [npm,: not found
```

Comment: I solved the problem ad, the problem is because of the double quote over the CMD. Just change the single quote to double quote. Problem solved. CMD ["npm", "start"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm not found when running docker container from node image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896245/npm-not-found-when-running-docker-container-from-node-image)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Run NPM command then you have to choose the base image as node instead of alpine

node:alpine ==> which pull the alpine node image

```
# Specify the Base image
  From node:alpine

# Install some dependencies
  RUN npm Install

# Default command
  CMD ["npm", "start"]
```